# how can i implement curl effect in MuPDF?

Tags: android

I am working on mupdf to implement curl page effect.now my mupdf running well but i want to implement curl effect on page so can any buddy know that how can i do this with mupdf ?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: @kyogs After 3 years. did you find any solution?!